# Setting up SimpleMembership in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am reading that in MVC4 to set up simple membership I should do this step:

In the AppSettings include a line:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
```

However when I look at the samples generated from the templates they only have:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

So why do I keep reading it's necessary to set the enableSimpleMembership key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the `SimpleMembershipProvider` is enabled when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application. But some hosting providers might disable it by overriding this setting in a higher level web.config.

Quote from an article about [SimpleMembership](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership):

> If you see an error that tells you that a property must be an
>   instance of ExtendedMembershipProvider, the site might not be
>   configured to use the ASP.NET Web Pages membership system
>   (SimpleMembership). This can sometimes occur if a hosting provider's
>   server is configured differently than your local server. To fix this,
>   add the following element to the site's Web.config file:
>
> `<appSettings>`
>
> ```
>    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
> ```
>
> `</appSettings>`

This setting is used by the `WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode` method which executes automatically when your site runs and will use the value of this setting to enable the simple membership provider.

Actually configuring the `SimpleMembershipProvider` explicitly is what I would recommend you:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership> 
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now, there's no room for confusion anymore. Both the membership and role providers are configured explicitly.

Comment: So just to clarify. I am running on Windows Azure. So you would suggest not to bother about the first code block setting where it adds a key in your answer but suggest me to add the membership and roleManager directly in my web.config as in your last code block of your answer?