# Asp.net MVC 4.5 Membership Provider with External Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am completely lost in how to use an external database for authentication/membership.

The answer in this question ([Setting up SimpleMembership in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170726/setting-up-simplemembership-in-mvc4)) is what I am looking for, although it is for MVC 4, and it looks like MVC 4.5 no longer uses WebMatrix/SimpleMembership.

Does anyone have a sample of the webconfig options for the membershipprovider and rolemanager?

Also, is there an easy way to create a database with just the tables needed for MVC 4.5 membership?

I am looking for the Asp Identity equivalent to this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Are you using AspNet Identity by chance?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I am trying to use whatever the default provider for 4.5 is. I need to break it apart from the database of my application, so it can be used for two separate applications with the same logins. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am aware of an MVC4 and and MVC5, but not an MVC4.5.  Please confirm which version you are using.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Ok. It is MVC4 with .NET 4.5

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: This is what I need to use, but in all of these demos, they are using the default local database.

Comment: You can change the connection string to some other database.

Comment: If I was to change the connection string to another database, would that not move the entire database(not just the identity tables)? I have to have my authentication completely separate from the rest of the application database. This is why I think I need to explicitly name the connection string within membership in web.config, but can't figure out how with Identity

Comment: You would need to maintain two separate `DbContext`'s, one for ASPNET.Identity and the other for the rest of your application.  That would imply two connection strings for your application.

Comment: I do understand that, the only thing is how do I let Identity know which context/connection string to use? Is it defined in the IdentityConfig.cs?

Comment: Is this where I would specify the separate context? var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

Comment: The `ApplicationDbContext` constructor will allow you to pass in a specific database connection string name.  I suggest that you actually add it to your project, and then inspect the code first, then come back with follow-up questions

Comment: This is what I needed to figure out. Thank you!